# Is it foot towel or feet towel?

Tags: terminology

Some online [links](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.amazon.co.uk/Foot-Towels/b%3Fie%3DUTF8%26node%3D3178075031&ved=2ahUKEwjnmszs4MnqAhUVAWMBHbUZDe0QFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw0qRUI7EAnHjjhz8b9aDUY1) use "foot towel" to describe "a small, rectangular towel typically used to dry the feet upon emerging from the shower or bath", while other [links](https://www.etsy.com/market/feet_towels) use "feet towel" to describe the same thing. So who is right in this context? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a compound noun, the first part is generally singular, even if multiple of those things are capable of being used or served by the overall compound noun.

This applies not just to body parts (foot towel, eye protection, lung capacity, finger bowl), but to other compound nouns as well (car wash, book club, student center, dog park).

Comment: Thank you all for the detailed explanations!

Answer (score 1):

It would be "foot towel" (by analogy with "hand towel"), but for what it's worth I've never heard of such a thing. I just use a bath mat outside the shower stall.

Comment: Attribution isn't necessary (but thanks). I posted a comment rather than an answer because I wasn't able to definitively rule out "foot towels" being a genuine item in some English-speaking culture I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Thank you so very much !