# (Singular or Plural Noun Adjunct) Stories Feature or Story Feature?

Tags: adjectives, adjuncts

What should we call the feature in Instagram and other websites that lets you post stories -
**"stories feature"**
or
**"story feature"?**

This question is similar: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/396864/singular-plural-nouns-as-adjectives

The answers there suggest me to use the singular ("story feature") but for some reason that doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: "Story" is correct.  See the answer to [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/253668/is-it-foot-towel-or-feet-towel/253699).

Comment: @CanadianYankee Are you sure? It seems like there are cases where that rule doesn't hold. Did you check the answer to the question I linked in the question description?

Comment: The answer to the question you linked gives five situations where the plural is used.  Which situation do you think might apply here? It seems to me that none of them do.

Comment: After a little poking around, it seems to me that talking about the feature in a generic sense, "story feature" is probably correct - searching on that exact phrase returns over a million Google hits and the top ones are all about a feature that lets you create stories.  However, for Instagram in particular, the feature is named "Instagram Stories", so "Stories feature" (with a capital S) is the proper name for that feature.

Comment: At the end of the answer it is written: _"However, this is more of an explanation rather than a rule you can use. There are too many exceptions, ...
Note that we often "choose by ear and it doesn’t matter (employee lounge, employees lounge)" (Chicago Manual of Style)."_

Even though it doesn't fit any of the five rules, In this case it sounds to me that the "Stories Feature" is a bit more clear. Maybe It could be that they call it the "Instagram Stories" like you pointed out!